# Can we always statically determine which functions will be invoked at compile time(not at runtime)?

Tags: solidity

**A question in one sentence**:

Regarding function call expressions in Solidity, can we always statically determine which functions will be invoked at compile time(not at runtime)?

**Example Code**:

```
contract A {
    uint256 public n;
    function set () public {
        n = 50;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function set () public {
        n = 40;
    }
}

contract C is A,B {
    function test (uint n) public {
        A a;
        if (n==1){
            a = new A();
        } 
        else{
            a = B(new B());
        }
        a.set(); // member of A or B?
    }
}
```

Considering Java programs, it seems that, ***at compile time***, we cannot determine whether the “set” function, invoked in the "test" function in contract C, is a member function of A contract or B contract. However, inspecting AST generated by a Solidity compiler (with an option solc --ast-compact-json), the invoked “set” function is referred as a member of A contract, not B contract. Is it an intentional feature of Solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you declare

```
A a;
```

And you invoke

```
a.set();
```

Your contract has no idea that `a` might be pointing to an instance of `B`.

Borrowing from you java statement: the call will resolved at "runtime".

Solidity compiles to: call function `set()` at address `a`. It doesn't care what contract is at that address, it might be a totally different contract.

For example the following will work as expected even when `A` and `B` and totally unrelated.

```
contract A {
    uint public n;
    function foo () public returns (uint) {
        n = 1234;
        return n;
    }
}

contract B {
    uint public n;
    function foo () public returns (uint) {
        n = 7777;
        return n;
    }
}

contract C {
    function bar(uint n) public returns (uint) {
        A a;
        if (n == 1) {
            a = new A();
        } else {
            a = A(address(new B()));
        }
        a.foo();
        return a.n();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how do we call a function.  There are several options:

Direct internal calls

```
function foo () public {
   ...
}

function bar () public {
   foo (); // Here call destination is statically determined
}
```

Indirect internal calls

```
function foo () public {
   ...    
}

function bar () public {
    ...
}

function zoo () public {
    function () func = block.timestamp & 1 == 0 ? foo : bar;
    func (); // Here call destination is determined at run time
}
```

Direct external calls

```
function foo (IERC20 _token) public {
    require (_token.transfer (msg.sender, 10)); // Here call destination is determined at run time
}
```

Indirect external calls

```
function foo (address _contract, bytes _data) {
    require (_contract.call (_data)); // Here called function is determined by first four bytes of _data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules are simple:

- External calls are always dynamic and involve Solidity method dispatcher
- Internal calls are always static and resolved in compile time

Example:

```
function foo() public {
    // ...
}

function bar() public {
    this.foo();  // external call
    foo();       // internal call
    super.bar(); // internal call
}
```

Solidity compiler transforms multiple inheritance into linear inheritance. So after compilation every smart contract will have a single parent, which can be accessed by `super` keyword. Maybe following example will help you to understand how [C3 inheritance linearization works](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization):

```
contract A { }
contract B { }
contract C is A, B { } // C(A,B) = ABC
contract D is C, A { } // D(C(A,B),A) = D(ABC,A) = ABCAD  Error
contract E is A, C { } // E(A,C(A,B)) = E(A,ABC) = ABCE
```